# Transfer big string to another device

Tags: android

In my app I want to send data in string to another device.

What i have now: sending data via QR-code with help of installed messengers (user can pick any like skype).
But it has a limit - nearly 4000 chars.

To clarify: I want to make a system, that can send some info on any distance in some way and receive and parse it next.

Any ideas?

Comment: Wi-Fi Direct or Bluetooth

Comment: Should be possible to transfer data on any distance, will edit question

Comment: @Vadim Please do _not_ add additional information in comments. There is an ``edit`` button below your question, _use it..._

Comment: [aSmack](https://github.com/Flowdalic/asmack)

Comment: Then I think you have to send this data to server and store it there and fetch it on another device

Comment: @HarshPatel is there really no way to store string in picture for example? Or may be save string to file and then send it?

Comment: what are your exact needs can you please elaborate??

Comment: you want to send file or string through internet right??

Comment: @HarshPatel Anyway to send string data (but now sending qr-code as picture)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should create a .txt file with that text and you can share it with any messenger.

Comment: That's a good idea too but I think he needs to send image file as well as text of only text at some instance

Comment: If it is an image then it can be sent as an image file like somename.png/somename.jpeg directly from device.

Comment: Yeah no issue then'

Answer (score 1):

I think setting up the server is the best solution according to me. Moreover, you can use Firebase database or firebase storage to store your images or stirng. This will allow you to fetch any type to data from anywhere in the world

Comment: So, the mechanics will be: i upload file with string or just string to Firebase and then somehow tell another device about upload and then download from it?

Comment: ya you can use firebase notification to notify that device

Comment: or else you can check constantly about the latest updates in background using the firebase methods

Comment: Thats good point too, but sending text file should be much easier to implement. Thanks anyway

Comment: Yeah which ever way you feel is the best